# Edit data with specific id

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a edit button for announcement but when I edit it, all the announcements change. I want to edit the specific id only. Here's my code:

```
   <?php
   if(mysql_num_rows($query_announcement) > 0)
   {
        $row = mysql_num_rows($query_announcement);
        for($x = 1; $x<= $row; $x++){

            $get_announcement= mysql_fetch_assoc($query_announcement);
            $html = '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td>'.$get_announcement['id'].'</td>';
            $html .= '<td>'.$get_announcement['announce_name'].'</td>';
            $html .= '<td>'.$get_announcement['announce_description'].'</td>';
            $html .= '<td>'.$get_announcement['announce_location'].'</td>';
            $html .= '<td>'.date('M d,Y', strtotime($get_announcement['date_start'])).'</td>';
            $html .= '<td>'.$get_announcement['date_end'].'</td>';
            $html .= '<td>'.date('M d,Y', strtotime($get_announcement['date_added'])).'</td>';
            $html .= '<td width="15%">

                <button type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_addAnnouncementEdit"  class="btn btn-default" title="Edit"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></button>
                <button type="button"class="btn btn-default" title="Delete" ><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></button>

            </td>';
            $html .= '</tr>';

            echo $html;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="8" align="center"><h3>No Announcement</h3></td></tr>';
    }
    ?>
```

**EDIT MODAL:**

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="modal_addAnnouncementEdit" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel"><span class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-fw fa-lg"></span> Edit Announcement</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="form_addAnnouncementEdit">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Title:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">

                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addAnnouncement_title_edit" name="addAnnouncement_title_edit" placeholder="Title">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addAnnouncement_description_edit" name="addAnnouncement_description_edit" placeholder="Description">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Location:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addAnnouncement_location_edit" name="addAnnouncement_location_edit" placeholder="Location">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date Start:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="addAnnouncement_dateStart_edit" name="addAnnouncement_dateStart_edit" placeholder="Date Start">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Time:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addAnnouncement_dateEnd_edit" name="addAnnouncement_dateEnd_edit" placeholder="Time">
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addAnnouncement_save_submit" name="addAnnouncement_save_submit" >Save Changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**MY UPDATE QUERY:**

```
<?php
require"../includes/library/DB.php";

$title = $_POST['addAnnouncement_title_edit'];
$description = $_POST['addAnnouncement_description_edit'];
$location = $_POST['addAnnouncement_location_edit'];
$date_start = $_POST['addAnnouncement_dateStart_edit'];
$date_end = $_POST['addAnnouncement_dateEnd_edit'];
$date_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query_announcement = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM announcement");
$get_announcement = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_announcement);
$insert_announcement = mysql_query("UPDATE `loanapplicationform`.`announcement` SET `announce_name` = '$title', `announce_description` = '$description', `announce_location` = '$location',
`date_start` = '$date_start', `date_end` = '$date_end' WHERE `announcement`.`id`=`$id`");

?>
```

please help me with this thanks for your answer I will really Appreciate it

Comment: you need to use a variable rather than the `id` column in your `where` clause, that's why it's updating your entire `id` column. Usually one with a hidden attribute

Comment: i already change it to $id , .$get_announcement['id'] but it doesn;t work. @Fred-ii-

Comment: You didn't assign anything to it. `$id = "?";` for example.

Comment: what's the syntax? I new here sorry, @Fred-ii-

Comment: Try `$id = $get_announcement['id'];` placed above `$title = $_POST['addAnnouncement_title_edit'];`

Comment: but you also need to remove both `\`` around the `$id` variable and use regular quotes `'$id'`

Comment: It doesn't work... @Fred-ii-

Comment: I don't know what else, sorry

Comment: Echo out your statement and see of it's what you expect: `echo "UPDATE loanapplicationform.announcement SET announce_name = '$title', announce_description = '$description', announce_location = '$location',
date_start = '$date_start', date_end = '$date_end' WHERE announcement.id ='$id'";`

Answer (score 0):

In your `MY UPDATE QUERY` part, you need to define `$id`.

This is your query:

```
$insert_announcement = mysql_query("UPDATE    
`loanapplicationform`.`announcement` SET `announce_name` = '$title',   
`announce_description` = '$description', `announce_location` = '$location',
`date_start` = '$date_start', `date_end` = '$date_end' WHERE
 `announcement`.`id`=`$id`");
```

When it is being executed, it doesn't know what `$id` is. So it will treat your WHERE clause as

```
...WHERE `announcement`.`id`=
```

Instead of

```
...WHERE `announcement`.`id`='abc12345'
```

And when you just simply replace `$id` with `$get_announcement['id']` will not work, because `$get_announcement['id']` only contain value within your loop.

You need to define `$id` where you define all other variables, for example:

```
$id = $_POST['addAnnouncement_id_edit'];

$title = $_POST['addAnnouncement_title_edit'];
$description = $_POST['addAnnouncement_description_edit'];
...
...
```